# Sqlite upsert from select with conflict does not always update row

Tags: sqlite, upsert

Assuming a database built with the following:

```sql
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;

CREATE TABLE foo (
  id   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  name TEXT NOT NULL,

  UNIQUE (name)
);
INSERT INTO foo (name) VALUES ('one'), ('two'), ('three');

CREATE TABLE bar (
   id    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
   key   TEXT    NOT NULL,
   fooID INTEGER NOT NULL,

   FOREIGN KEY (fooID) REFERENCES foo(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
   UNIQUE (key)
);
```

If I want to insert into a value into the table `bar` (here represented by the 'key' string, but in the real world it would be parameterized and this would be `$1` and the 'three' would be `$2`) using the name field from `foo` I tried something like the following:

```sql
INSERT INTO bar (key, fooID)
  SELECT 'key', foo.id FROM foo WHERE foo.name='three'
  ON CONFLICT (key) DO UPDATE SET fooID=excluded.id;
```

But it only sometimes seems to update the existing row, eg. in the above contrived example if I go from using 'three' for `foo.name` to 'two' it updates fine, but if I then run again with 'three' it does not update.

```
sqlite> delete from bar
sqlite> INSERT INTO bar (key, fooID) SELECT 'key', foo.id FROM foo WHERE foo.name='three' ON CONFLICT (bar.key) DO UPDATE SET fooID=excluded.id;
sqlite> select * from bar;
1|key|3
sqlite> INSERT INTO bar (key, fooID) SELECT 'key', foo.id FROM foo WHERE foo.name='two' ON CONFLICT (bar.key) DO UPDATE SET fooID=excluded.id;
sqlite> select * from bar;
1|key|2
sqlite> INSERT INTO bar (key, fooID) SELECT 'key', foo.id FROM foo WHERE foo.name='three' ON CONFLICT (bar.key) DO UPDATE SET fooID=excluded.id;
sqlite> select * from bar;
1|key|2
```

Other variations on `excluded.id` that I've tried either don't exist or don't work. Can someone explain the behavior here, or possibly how I can print a list of column names in the excluded row or another way I might debug this (or possibly even a better way to do the insert I'm trying to do)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here appears to come from a misunderstanding of the "excluded" keyword. The [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html) states:

> To use the value that would have been inserted had the constraint not failed, add the special "excluded." table qualifier to the column name.

The value that *would* have been inserted into `fooID` is of course `excluded.fooID`, not `excluded.id` as I have in the example above. I believe `external.id` refers to the *row ID* of the column, which in this case would have been 2 for the third row.

So the final query we end up with is:

```sql
INSERT INTO bar (key, fooID)
  SELECT 'key', foo.id FROM foo WHERE foo.name='three'
  ON CONFLICT (key) DO UPDATE SET fooID=excluded.fooID;
```